# FromJson Expected BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, file, serialization, gson, streamwriter

hi have some trouble finding what's wrong with my Json parser.

Hi have an object student (ID,Name,Grade)
This is how i write my student in my document :
        public void run() {

```
        System.out.println("Server get:" + value);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
            System.out.println("this record will be created in the source document");
             String json = gson.toJson(value);
          //   System.out.println(json);

             //2. Convert object to JSON string and save into a file directly
                try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(File,true)) {

                    gson.toJson(value, writer);
                    writer.write("\n");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

In the document i get that 
{"SID":"fd36ac24-4487-49aa-bdd0-40535b55d081","Name":"Marie","Major":"IT"}

which is a good student object. And now I want to get this file information into a student object again. This is how i try to do it :

```
    public Student Creation_Two() {
            String fichier ="C:\\Users\\programming\\Personne_source.txt";              
         Student s1 = new Student();        

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    System.out.println("we try to parse the document with json to the object");



                    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(fichier));    
                    reader.setLenient(true);
                    System.out.println("reader value "+reader);                 
                    try
                    {                                                       
                    s1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Student.class);                                      
                    System.out.println(s1 +" s1 have been serialized");
                    return s1;  

                    }
                    catch (IllegalStateException | JsonSyntaxException e1)
                    {
                         System.out.println("error in getting the object");
                         e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return s1;              
    }
```

But that didn't work i have the error : Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 2.

here is the student class

```
public class Student {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String SID;
    private String Name;
    private String Major;

public Student(String SID, String Name, String Major)
{
    this.setSID(SID);
    this.setName(Name);
    this.setMajor(Major);
}

public Student() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student SID= " + SID + ", Name= " + Name + ", Major= " + Major + "";
}
//all the get set
```

Comment: could you paste the Student class?

Comment: I edited the question to put the class now.

Comment: Do not be initializing `s1`, just say `Student s1 = gson.fromJson(reader, Student.class);` also, `JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(fichier));` you are using the wrong reader, that reads in a string, you need a filereader.

Comment: @thor did you try the option i told you?

Comment: @cralfaro yes I test it and still the error I printed the console output beside. But I think i have to modify something because i can have a random number of student in my file and I have to serialize just n number of student

Comment: also, another thing, remove the `serialVersionUID ` that is for the java serializer/deserializer only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println("this record will be created in the source document");
String fichier ="C:\\Users\\programming\\Personne_source.txt";
byte[] encoded =Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fichier));
System.out.println("JSON: " + new String(encoded, "UTF-8"));
Student s1 = new Student();
try
{
    s1 = gson.fromJson(new String(encoded, "UTF-8"), Student.class);
    System.out.println(s1 +" s1 have been serialized");
}
catch (IllegalStateException | JsonSyntaxException e1)
{
    System.out.println("error in getting the object");
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(s1.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i tried your code this is what i get in the console

```
JSON: {"SID":"577f484b-6ff8-4fbd-aa9d-1d7842874a03","Name":"Paul","Major":"IT"}
{"SID":"fd36ac24-4487-49aa-bdd0-40535b55d081","Name":"Marie","Major":"IT"}
error in getting the object
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 2 column 1
Student SID= null, Name= null, Major= null
at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:772)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:762)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:682)
at Accepter_clients_Two.Creation_Two(Serveur_Two.java:275)
at Accepter_clients_Two.run(Serveur_Two.java:71)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So kind of the same thing and i don't understand because the JSON out input is good.
But can it be because I have more than one JSON object in my document ?

Comment: i have it working with exactly the same code. Verify please you dont have any break line at the end of your txt file or empty space at the end

Comment: @cralfaro yes I find the way to do it now. I have to work on my writing the object again and get the good number of student.

Comment: great i hope the code help you to find your solution